# Downgrade OpenSSL on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, openssl

Application I use requires OpenSSL 0.9.8, which was already installed (0.9.8e to be specific) on my CentOS alongside 1.0.1e which unfortunately is used by default. I tried to change `libssl.so.10` symbolic link to point to the older version like so:

```
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl 
/usr/bin/openssl: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2edff000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f664457c000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003927600000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003926200000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003925a00000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003926e00000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003927200000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000391a600000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x000000391aa00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003919e00000)
    libcrypto.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00007f664421d000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003925e00000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003926a00000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x000000391be00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000391a200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003919600000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000000391b600000)
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/mckulpa/libs:/usr/local/Nuance/Recognizer_Service/amd64/lib:/usr/local/Nuance/OAM/x86/lib:/usr/local/Nuance/Common/x86/lib:/usr/local/Nuance/Common/amd64/lib
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl 
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/mckulpa/libs/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff91dbc000)
    libssl.so.10 => /home/mckulpa/libs/libssl.so.10 (0x00007ffe1af50000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x0000003927600000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x0000003926200000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0000003925a00000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x0000003926e00000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x0000003927200000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x000000391a600000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x000000391aa00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003919e00000)
    libcrypto.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.6 (0x00007ffe1abd9000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x0000003925e00000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x0000003926a00000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x000000391be00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x000000391a200000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003919600000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x000000391b600000)
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ ls -l libs
total 316
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mckulpa mckulpa 321224 05-28 14:59 libssl.so.0.9.8e
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 mckulpa mckulpa     16 05-28 15:18 libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
```

but all I get is a warning and still the 1.0.1e version is printed out:

```
[mckulpa@nuance-vm ~]$ openssl version
openssl: /home/mckulpa/libs/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by openssl)
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Any ideas how to do this properly?

Comment: As part of building OpenSSL, you should have built the binary.  Run the new binary (perhaps `/home/mckulpa/bin/openssl`?).

Comment: If you _really_ have a binary application that _requires_ OpenSSL 0.9.8, you should run it on a system that has that version of OpenSSL already, such as CentoS 5 (not CentOS 6).

Comment: @MadHatter I did not build OpenSSL unfortunately, I copied libssl.so.0.9.8e from /usr/lib64 directory. I might try building it though if no easier solutions will be suggested.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I will probably do that if everything else fails but I  wish there was some other solution as I would really like to be able to use it on newer systems (not only CentOS but also Debian)

Comment: Upgrade the application, then?

Comment: Your work above simply modifies the environment for `/usr/bin/openssl`, but it sounds like you actually want to modify the environment for your custom application (`Nuance` perhaps?). You don't want `ldd /usr/bin/openssl`, you want `ldd /path/to/your/application`. `/usr/bin/openssl` is provided by OpenSSL 1.0.1 and is only intended to be used with that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application needs the 0.9.8 openssl -- but does it need the 0.9.8 openssl executable, or the 0.9.8 library? (Is it trying to run openssl, or link against it?)

The CentOS openssl098e package is a "A compatibility version of a general cryptography and TLS library", and will install the libraries only - it will not install the 0.9.8 executable.

Run ldd against your application to see whether it's linking in one of the openssl libraries (libssl and libcrypto).  To see what your application is trying to run, you can strace it with `strace -fo /tmp/strace.out` and look for the execv lines.

If your application needs the openssl executable, you'd need to recompile the 0.9.8 package for CentOS 6.

If your application needs the openssl library, then verify whether you need the x86_64 or i686 version, with `ldd application`. If it's looking in /lib64, then `yum install yum install openssl098e.x86_64`. If it's looking in /lib then `yum install openssl098e.i686`.

Comment: I was only suggested by support that it needs openssl 0.9.8 without mentioning whether its library or executable. I suppose it was meant to be executable as ldd doesn't show any version of libssl. Thanks, I will try to compile it myself then.

Comment: What about `libcrypto`?  This is also provided by the `openssl` package(s).

Comment: You are right, I wasn't aware of that - there was a libcrypto dependency (now i see @R Perrin also suggested that). The application now seems to work... I believe what helped after installing 0.9.8 was the removal of devel package of openssl 1.0.1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If anyone is reading this then I might want to add that doing the same thing I did with libssl in my question but with libcrypto (that is changing so's through LD_LIBRARY_PATH) would have probably worked as well and might be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 6):

Copying single libraries from other machines is an exercise almost guaranteed to fail, likely in strange and difficult-to-diagnose ways.  Don't do that, and if you must do it don't describe it as "*installed*"; that process definitely doesn't constitute installation.

There does appear to be an `openssl098e` RPM in the CentOS 6 base repository, which means it's very likely to be in RHEL6 as well.  It will be packaged to coexist peacefully with the main system OpenSSL, and it seems to contain the necessary libraries for something that absolutely **must** have the old version.  It doesn't have the userspace `openssl` tool, but I'd be quite surprised if your application required that.

Try doing a `yum install openssl098e`.

Comment: I'm sorry... I probably wasn't clear enough. Openssl098e was already installed. I didn't copy it from other machine, I just copied it from /usr/lib64 from the same machine to my home directory in order to reconfigure LD_LIBRARY_PATH (which worked as ldd command shows). I wanted to point the executable to a different library. But as it has already been suggested i might need to recompile.

Comment: They are right; the executable doesn't work like that.  But I'd still be very surprised if another tool needed the userspace binary rather than the libraries; check my comment above about `libcrypto`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `openssl 0.9.8` binary on CentOS 6.5, then just download the source from here: https://www.openssl.org/source/ , compile and install it (there's instruction in `INSTALL` file in downloaded source) and it will work fine.

Don't forget to set up paths properly, so that yo could find that binary in a place you expect it to be (`/usr/bin/openssl`, `/usr/local/bin/openssl`, etc.)